# different values in same column, output in different columns

Tags: mysql

Currently I am working on a project, which has to do with Formula 1.

That's my structure of the table for results.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `races_results` (
  `resultid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seasonyear` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `trackid` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `raceid` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `session` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `q` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `place` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `driverid` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `teamid` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `laps` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My big problem is that I don't get the result in output as I want.

```
SELECT place, driverid, teamid, if(q=1, time, '') as time1, if(q=2, time, '') as time2, if(q=3, time, '') as time3 
FROM `races_results` 
WHERE `seasonyear` = 2015 AND `raceid` = 3 AND `session` = 2 AND `q` IN (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY driverid 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN q = 3 THEN place >= 1 AND place <= 10 END ASC, CASE WHEN q = 2 THEN place >= 11 AND place <= 16 END ASC, CASE WHEN q = 1 THEN place >= 17 AND place <= 22 END ASC
```

My target is that I want that the all times of a driver will show side by side and after this should be ordered by the participants of the sections.

After this I should have an output like this http://www.formula1.com/content/fom-website/en/championship/results/2015-race-results/2015-japan-results/qualifying.html

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that the table `races_results` has a line for each result, so the times of the different qualifications are on different lines. To get these on one line you can do a join of the same table:

```
SELECT place, driverid, teamid, r1.time as time1, r2.time as time2, r3.time as time3
FROM races_results r1 LEFT JOIN races_results r2 on (r1.driverid=r2.driverid and r1.raceid=r2.raceid)
LEFT JOIN races_results r3 on (r1.driverid=r3.driverid and r1.raceid=r3.raceid)
WHERE r1.q=1 AND r2.q=2 AND r3.q=3 AND
`seasonyear` = 2015 AND `raceid` = 3 AND `session` = 2 
GROUP BY driverid 
ORDER BY place;
```

I assume:

- that there is always a result for q=1;
- the `driverid` and `raceid` are unique for a race on a specific year for a driver;
- you want to order by place.

Comment: Thanks, that's brings me closer to my target. Now I only have to look how I get the time of q2 and q3 for time2 and time3. Currently I get the time of the practice for time2 and time3.

Comment: I updated my answer because I forgot to add:  `r1.q=1 AND r2.q=2 AND r3.q=3`.

Comment: My way was through subqueries. It's solved now. Thanks for helping.